# How to retrieve one single value from local storage array in ionic2/angular2

Tags: arrays, html, angular, ionic2

I have populated an array like this:

```
`public IamanArray;
public MYARRAY(array: Array<any>)
{
this.localStorage.set('IamanArray',array);
}`
```

I need a simple way to access, let's say value at index [1] of this array.
Is there a simple way to do it?

I have tried :

```
`this.localStorage.get('IamanArray[1]');`
```

but it won't work.

Any suggestion?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small error, it should be getItem:

```
let arr = localStorage.getItem('IamanArray');
let value = arr[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

you would need to extract the item first and then get the item:

```
public extraData(): any {
    let iamanArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('IamanArray'));
    return iamanArray[1];
}
```

Also your set should be as follows:

```
public MYARRAY(array: Array<any>) {
    localStorage.setItem('IamanArray', array);
}
```

Comment: `public extraData(a): any {
     this.localStorage.get('IamanArray').then(data => {
     let receiver = data;
     console.log(this.receiver[a].mykey);
    });
}`

Comment: somehow it worked like that.. parse.JSON did complain. thanks!

Comment: Ok I see now, this is with Ionic2. Ionic does not use the default localStorage. When you retrieve an item from localstorage it returns a promise.